# Moving selected Data by check box from Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cnv0.png)Some one could help me on my question?

Below is my code for copying data, using Checkbox macros.  I would like to modify it to move the selected data by checkbox  from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`. The Source Data should be erased from Source Location (`Sheet1`).

```
Sub CopyRows()
    For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
            For r = 1 To Rows.Count
                If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        .Range("A" & LRow & ":I" & LRow) = _
                        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":I" & r).Value
                    End With
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly only a small change is required, but if you want to delete the rows try the last line of code.

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim r As Long, LRow As Long

For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("A" & LRow & ":I" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":I" & r).Value
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":I" & r).ClearContents 'will leave blank cells
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next

'line below will delete any rows where column A is blank so you may not want to use this
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A8", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End with

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello with the above code for moving I got error - Runtime Error '9' - Subscript out of Range.

Comment: .Range("A" & LRow & ":Z" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("Stock").Range("A" & r & ":Z" & r).Value                         This is the part where It highlighted error in yellow.

Comment: That's your code, I didn't touch. If it's on a single line remove the underscore. Do you definitely have a sheet called Stock?

Comment: Yes. Sheet1 is named as 'Stock' and Sheet2 is named as 'TO Delivery'

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug and work out what is going on? There is nothing obviously wrong so I can't really tell.

Comment: It was the problem with the Sheet Ref. When I use renamed reference. it shows the error I mentioned. If I use Sheet1 and Sheet2. It is runs perfect..????

Comment: Hallo @SJR . There is one problem I had encountered. Please look into the picture now I have updated. when I select and move a data, for example the S.No which is below, the rows above the Title Row are deleted automatically. Could you explain why it is..? and how to get rid of it..

Comment: I've amended the last section above which I think should do the trick. Amend the A8 as necessary to whichever row your data starts on.